# Excel Scatter Plot shows strange lines

Tags: excel, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot a data similar to this:

```
| X | Y |

| 0.0056 | 0.6878 |

| 0.0083 | 0.6807 |

| 0.0139 | 0.6593 |

| 0.0194 | 0.6273 |

| ...  | ... |
```

However, the plot always shows up like the image below. I have checked the data and nothing is wrong. It happens when plotting other similar dataset as well, but not all.

[image: Wrong scatter plot]

Comment: Looks like I found the issue. Excel's smoothed line feature does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not user error? I typed your data in and got what seems to be the correct result using a scatter plot with line smoothing?

[image]

Comment: Yes I am sure unfortunately. My data has over ten thousands data point. Excel for some reason does not like that. I did not even change the chart type or any data. As soon as I untick the smooth line option in the series formatting the problem goes away. This is true for all the plots that had this issue.